# Accessing Sitecore Login from each site in a multi-site setup fails (404 page not found) for only one site

Tags: sitecore-client, site-configuration, multisite

We have a multi-site instance of Sitecore 8.2 and we have patched the `<sites>` section to include each site. This all seems fine and every site can be accessed by its unique domain/subdomain.

Curiously, one of the sites will resolve fine (it's home page), but when we try to access Sitecore, instead of loading the login page, we get a 404 page.

Here's the config line for a site that works -

> Sitecore login page is reachable

*Note I only changed the hostnames to generic values (e.g site1 and oursite.com):*

```
<site patch:after="*[@name='modules_website']"
    name="site1_authoring"
    targetHostName="authoring.site1.oursite.com"
    hostName="authoring.site1.oursite.com"
    virtualFolder="/"
    physicalFolder="/"
    rootPath="/sitecore/content"
    startItem="/Sites/site1"
    database="web"
    enableAnalytics="false"
    domain="extranet"
    allowDebug="true"
    cacheHtml="true"
    htmlCacheSize="100MB"
    registryCacheSize="0"
    viewStateCacheSize="0"
    xslCacheSize="5MB"
    filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
    enablePreview="true"
    enableWebEdit="true"
    enableDebugger="true"
    disableClientData="false"
    forceSSL="false" />
```

And here's the config line for the site that does not work -

> CANNOT access Sitecore login page

*Note I only changed the hostnames to generic values (e.g site2 and oursite.com):*

```
<site patch:after="*[@name='modules_website']"
    name="site2_authoring"
    targetHostName="authoring.site2.oursite.com"
    hostName="authoring.site2.oursite.com"
    virtualFolder="/"
    physicalFolder="/"
    rootPath="/sitecore/content/Sites/site2"
    startItem="/Home"
    database="web"
    domain="extranet"
    enableAnalytics="false"
    allowDebug="true"
    cacheHtml="true"
    htmlCacheSize="100MB"
    registryCacheSize="0"
    viewStateCacheSize="0"
    xslCacheSize="5MB"
    filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB"
    enablePreview="true"
    enableWebEdit="true"
    enableDebugger="true"
    disableClientData="false"
    forceSSL="false" />
```

When trying to access the Sitecore login on the second site via:
`http://authoring.site2.oursite.com/Sitecore/login`, we get the following error:

`http://authoring.site2.oursite.com/error/pagenotfound?item=&user=sitecore%5cAnonymous&site=login`

I am not seeing anything significant in the site config definitions?

Comment: The rootPath and start item is not consistent between the two of them.

Comment: Do you have sitecore/login folder on that server? Do you have the ```<site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" />``` on that server also?

Comment: Are there any log errors?

Comment: Please go to `/sitecore/admin/ShowConfig.aspx`, find the `<sites>` section and attach its contents to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you find that something like this is happening and the `<sites>` configuration seems valid, consider, as I eventually did, that all sites are pointing to the same server.

When I pinged the working sites, I saw that they all had the same IP but the site throwing the 404 was pointing to a different IP, and therefore a different server altogether; one that did not have the Sitecore login folder as TRNKTMS alluded to.

Answer (score 3):

The clue here suggests that the login site is resolving correctly. The error message is forwarding to the pagenotfound using the site context of **login**. This tells me that the SiteResolver is picking up the correct site.

Something else is going on preventing access to the login page.

#### Things to Check:

- Make sure something funky isn't going on in IIS preventing access to the file structure of /sitecore/login for that domain.
- Try clearing cookies, cache, or using Incognito to make sure there isn't some strange cookie getting in the way.
- Ensure that your site definitions are properly ordered:

  - Order Includes:

    1. shell
    2. login
    3. admin
    4. service
    5. modules_shell
    6. modules_website
    7. SITE DEFINITIONS HERE
    8. scheduler
    9. system
    10. publisher

Comment: These are all great ideas and I did check each of these. It turned out that the site in question's DNS record had been pointed to the wrong server. One that didn't have a Sitecore login folder.

Comment: ahhh  pointed to a hardened CD instead!